# Is a 40 V/m electric field, coming from a wall socket and measured in air, a safety hazard?

Tags: electricity, everyday-life, biology

I used a gaussmeter close to my child’s crib. Her head faces about 1 foot away from an electric socket. I was surprised it measured about 40 V/m at the socket and then gradually went down but was still about 20 or so where she would be lying. Is this high and dangerous? Does something like a pillow and her mattress also act as an insulator? I thought 10 V and lower was considered safe. Seems like the number I got back was fairly high. Any comments?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about safety of everyday devices and not physics.

Comment: Did you think that the safe level was 10 V, or 10 V/m? Those quantities measure completely different things.

Comment: The electric field between the terminals of a standard AAA size battery is about 35 V/m. You are worrying about nothing - unless you think batteries are dangerous, of course. (They are dangerous if your child tries to *eat* one, but that is beside the point...)

Comment: Thank you for the response.

Answer (score 2):

Unless subjected to a high voltage gradient (much much higher than 40 V/m) air is an excellent insulator having ohmic resistance in the range of $10^9$ - $10^{15}$ Ohm-m at 20 C (per Wikipedia). This means the amount of current that can potentially flow through air at low voltages is minuscule compared to the current required to cause dangerous electric shock (ventricular fibrillation). That current is on the order of 10s to 100 mA at 60 Hz.

So as @Emilio Pisanty pointed out, the key is to not allow children to attempt to stick things into the outlet slots. Tamper resistant outlets reduce the risk of electric shock. One type of design blocks insertion of an object into only one slot, but does not block the simultaneous insertion of the two parallel blades of a plug into the outlet.

These safety devices, if properly tested and certified, can significantly reduce the risk of shock to children, but do not make the risk zero. In my opinion they are not intended to eliminate the need for adult supervision of very young children near electrical outlets. There are other dangers involved, not involving the outlet, but the cord. One is the possibility of severe mouth burns when children bit into cords.

I like to think of these devices as a backup to supervision because, as we all know, it (the device and supervision) can never be perfect. But having both best reduces the risks.

> Yes I guess I meant electromagnetic radiation. It seems that the
>   general online reference to “safe” and “typical” levels of v/m is 10.
>   Not sure if that’s a magic number or not. I was just at odds and
>   nervous as to why the reading I took came back higher and wanted to
>   know if it’s a concern I should take seriously because of where the
>   baby sleeps. Thank you!

Well then you are asking a different question. The biological effects of electromagnetic radiation are not generally based on voltage or voltage gradient, but rather the frequency of the electromagnetic radiation. Emilio and I have already covered extra low frequency (60 Hz). As the frequency increases the nature of the biological effects change. For an overview on those effects, google "interaction of electromagnetic radiation with matter" and go to the Hyperphysics web site.

So you need to separate radiation concerns from "safe" voltage issues. Now regarding "safe" voltage as it relates to electric shock consider the following. But firsts, as @tparker pointed out, V/m is not voltage but field strength. For a uniform field, multiply it by the distance between two points in the direction of the field and you get the potential difference (voltage) between the two points. So the potential difference between two points separated by a meter in the direction of a field of 40 V/m is then 40 volts.

That being said, voltage is not what causes electric shock. It is current through the body. And that depends not only on the source voltage, but that depends on the source impedance that limits current which, in the case of air, is normally very high.

Then you need to be very careful about what level of voltage is considered "safe" with respect to electric shock hazard. Because that also depends on other things including frequency, waveshape,  impedance of the skin, etc.. For dry and slightly moist skin contact conditions 60 hz voltage less than 30 vrms is, per many safety standards, considered low risk of electric shock. Under wet contact conditions, that drops to 15 vrms at 60 Hz. For immersed body conditions (such as in a pool) there is no "safe" voltage since the skin impedance is essentially zero. The available current to the body is principle criteria.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is there any risk of electric radiation as well at that level and distance?

Comment: @curiousv Electric radiation at mains frequency is not harmful (or rather, it is not any more harmful than DC fields).

Comment: @curiousv If you mean electromagnetic radiation from the power frequency (60 Hz) currents associated with the outlet, this is very low frequency and to my knowledge has not, to date, been shown to involve injurious biological effects. But research into the biological effects of low frequency electromagnetic radiation continues.

Comment: Yes I guess I meant electromagnetic radiation. It seems that the general online reference to “safe” and “typical” levels of v/m is 10. Not sure if that’s a magic number or not. I was just at odds and nervous as to why the reading I took came back higher and wanted to know if it’s a concern I should take seriously because of where the baby sleeps. Thank you!

Comment: V/m is a measure of electric field strength, not voltage.

Comment: @tparker I assume your comment was directed at the OP.

Comment: Does this change the answer to my question???

Comment: @tparker I see what you mean. I meant, of course, a high voltage gradient. I will edit.

Comment: @curiousv I've updated my answer to address biological hazards of electromagnetic radiation in addition to electric shock hazards, since your question appears to have changed

Comment: I'm not sure why my original answer was down voted since it answered the original question. Same for Emilio's answer.

Comment: @BobD typically answers to off-topic questions are downvoted, so it shouldn't be of any surprise to you at this point, no?

Comment: @KyleKanos I don't recall seeing off topic votes when I answered the question, otherwise I might not have. But I must say there have been other questions about the biological effects of radiation that were not voted off topic. And I think that is because there is underlying physics associated with the interaction of electromagnetic radiation with matter as shown in the Hyperphysics link I referenced. But alas I accept the decision of the judges. Thanks.

Comment: @KyleKanos I might also add that, as a safety engineer for nearly 50 year, I spent considerable time teaching our engineers and clients the underlying  engineering and physics behind safety requirements and that safety is not simply an "art" as some would claim it to be.

Comment: I agree that there is merit in safety, but strangers on the internet site isn't the place for it. There is a question or two on Physics Meta about safety questions that indicate it is off topic & answers shouldn't such subjects (though not codified in a FAQ)

Comment: Another thing worth pointing out is that the danger depends on which parts of the body come into contact with the voltage difference. The same voltage difference can be non-lethal if you connect it with a single fingertip (because the current flows through your fingertip), but lethal if you connect it with both of your hands (because the current flows across your heart from one hand to another).

Answer (score 0):

It could potentially be dangerous, if there were no insulating material between you and the socket.

Fortunately, however, air is an excellent insulator, and it will not conduct electricity until its dielectric breakdown threshold at about $3\times 10^6\:\rm V/m$.

In other words, make sure that your socket is made child-safe and that your child is not able to touch the metallic leads inside the socket, and that is sufficient.

Comment: Why was Emilio's answer down voted. It, like my original answer, responded to the original OP question.